# Analysis of java stack trace, what threads are running

Tags: java, multithreading, stack-trace, multicore

I'm analyzing stack trace dumps in java and don't know how I can tell which threads are actually running.  The way I see it a thread is either running, waiting on a lock, sleeping or waiting to be scheduled.

In my stack trace I see the following states

```
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
```

First, what exactly do these states mean?

Second, I have 11 threads that are `runnable`, two of which are waiting on a condition. Does that mean 9 threads are running simultaneously?  It doesn't seem possible since my machine doesn't have that amount of cores.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The term `Runnable` may not mean 'currently running' but rather 'is in a state of running'.  The differences as you eluded to is that the maximum number of threads that can be running at any given time is equal to your number of cores.

To understand it in more details, you would need to know what the other two mean.  `WAITING` would mean that a thread has been suspended on some object.

```
while(<condition holds>)
    obj.wait()
```

Here, the current thread is currently `WAITING` on obj's monitor.  This would force that thread to become suspended in which the OS can schedule another thread to run.

`TIMED_WAITING` is simply suspending a thread for a certain amount of time.

So if a thread isn't `wait`ing or `sleep`ing it is considered `run`ning.

To give more insights from the documentation.

> Thread state for a runnable thread. A
>   thread in the runnable state is
>   executing in the Java virtual machine
>   but it may be waiting for other
>   resources from the operating system
>   such as processor.

That last part is what I think you are looking for.  Physically the OS cannot run more threads in parallel than the amount of the cores.
All 9 of your threads may run concurrently but only `n` will run in parallel (`n` being the number of cores).

Similar is true for `Condition.await`

Edit:

Sorry richs - Should've linked my resource http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html#RUNNABLE

Comment: Where id you get that statement on a runnable thread.  Is it from the java language specification.

Answer (score 0):

See if this Page helps you
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html

To answer your second question about the number of cores vs threads. A core can have multiple threads running on it at once. Therefore # threads >= # cores

The full stack from each thread will give you a better understanding of what each is doing. If there is no work currently being done in the application, many will be sitting in a waiting state, read to accept its next job.

Comment: I was under the impression that the way a single core machine mutli-threaded was through time-slicing.

Comment: multiple threads run inside the same JVM. See the documentation on the Oracle site for more info on the inner workings